# Is it possible to access a process instance id from within the instance? (jbpm)

Tags: jbpm, bpmn

We're hoping to put a running instance id into context within our jbpm workflow so we can use it along with the remote queries to pull data back about our running application.

Anyone know if this is possible? And if so how is it done?

Comment: Maybe useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440523/jbpm-persistence-examples-resuming-a-workflow

Answer (score 15, accepted):

¿Where are you planing to do that?
On a "Script Task" you can access to a running process Instance with:

```
System.out.println("processInstanceId = "+kcontext.getProcessInstance().getId());
```